# convert String to array in php and make it dynamic

Tags: php, parse-platform

I need to make this string as array. Finally I need to make this $objectData as dynamic data

```
$objectData = '{"data": 
                    { "alert": "Notification From Nagesh", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" },
                    "where": {
                             "channels": { 
                                 "$in": ["b2b4d6cd85af729cf5692fdbb2e43dee93c3563493c9dba7e85a614622c10ba91f2"]
                              }
                    }
                }
             }';
```

Comment: Where's the code ? Have you attempted to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_decode`, but your string `$objectData` isn't a valid JSON it has a wrong bracket it should be:

```
$objectData = '{"data": 
                    { "alert": "Notification From Nagesh", "sound": "", "badge": "Increment" },
                    "where": {
                             "channels": { 
                                 "$in": ["b2b4d6cd85af729cf5692fdbb2e43dee93c3563493c9dba7e85a614622c10ba91f2"]
                            }
                    }
                }'; 

var_dump( json_decode($objectData));
```

Answer (score 0):

String looks like json object. So you can try `json_decode()` method for this string.

Read for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

This will return array

var_dump(json_decode($objectData, true));